# Teradata and Apache Kafka using Kafka connect

Tags: java, apache-kafka, teradata, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Apologies if my question is all over the place but I am new to Apache Kafka and currently I am trying to import data from a Teradata table (on a VM) into Kafka using my Windows OS. So far I've done the following:

1- Download Apache Kafka
2- Run the Kafka server and Zookeper.
3- Write a producer class in JAVA using IntelliJ IDE.
4- Consume the output of the producer through Kafka's `kafka-console-consumer.bat`script which comes with the downloaded zip for Apache Kafka.

I have read a few posts and found that to connect Kafka and Teradata I need to use Kafka connect. But a few things confuse me:

1- Most posts I've come across use Confluent. I have read that confluent is for Linux operating systems only. Is there a way to perform my task of ingesting data into Kafka without the use of Confluent?

2- I also know that I have to copy kafka-connect-jdbc jars to Kafka libs folder. Then I have to copy Teradata JDBC jars into Kafka lib folder.

What is the next step for integrating Teradata or any other database with Kafka? How do I create the configuration files in intelliJ and link those with Kafka?

Answer (score 2):

> confluent is for Linux operating systems only.

Confluent CLI, yes. Confluent Platform, no.

> Ingesting data into Kafka without the use of Confluent?

Sure. Kafka Connect is packaged with Apache Kafka, which Confluent distributes. Again, not OS limitation

> What is the next step for integrating Teradata or any other database with Kafka?

Run Kafka Connect using the scripts for Windows. Property files remain the same

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_user

Note that the JDBC connector only works with certain database dialects, and Teradata might not work as expected

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer , I'lll look into the link you shared and get back on this post with the results.

Comment: How can I find out the value for 'connector.class' for Teradata JDBC please?

Comment: so far I am facing the following issues:
1- The value for "connector.class" that I have used is com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver. Is this correct because it gives an error that "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"
2- I could not find the jdbc jar for kafka-connect in the default Apache Kafka download folder. I downloaded it from confluent and copied all the jars into the lib forlder for Kafka. Is this the correct way?
3-  For "topic.prefix"  I just used the name of my topic. I am not sure what prefix here means.

Comment: I added the following for my Teradata connector properties file:
name=teradata-source
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
replication.factor=1
connector.class=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
tasks.max=1
teradata.url=jdbc:teradata://192.168.239.140
teradata.database=dbc
teradata.username=dbc
teradata.password=dbc
topic.prefix=test_two
table.whitelist=dbc.dbcinfov

Do the above satisfy the bare minimum required to run Kafka connect? Or some additional properties have to be used as well?

Comment: Last question, is my approach incorrect to be experimenting with vanilla Apache Kafka instead of using Confluent Apache Kafka distribution because most online tutorials are for confluent? Which approach will make my job easier?

Comment: Properties look fine. There is no difference unless you use the `confluent` CLI command.

Comment: I'm back to square one as this approach did not work for some reason and I don't know what to modify in my Teradata connector properties file shared above. I have been also told that I can make a simple JDBC connection in my Java code for Producers/Consumers and that would make the data transfer easy. But so far I am unable to find any online tutorials for this. Everything points towards using connectors by confluent which is paid. How can I write my own custom connector for baseline Kafka please?

Comment: Confluent Community edition is not paid. Nor are their JDBC connectors. You should edit your question to include any errors you get with the Teradata connector